# How to Hibernate Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 from the GUI?

Tags: gnome, hibernate

I'm able to hibernate my system with the command `systemctl hibernate`. However If I try to hibernate it with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Shutdown menu, then my system is suspended instead of truly hibernate.

Is there anyway to hibernate from Gnome GUI?

The extension "Hibernate status button" have not solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is install [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/755/hibernate-status-button/) to GNOME. It will add hibernate button to power panel.

[image: Hibernate button preview]

Comment: The mentioned extension didn't help me. I still have only 3 buttons after installed it.

Comment: @Neo - Yes, I see some reviews from Ubuntu users. There must be some bug in compatibility with Ubuntu. I have Debian 10 and it works. So maybe you should find reason, why It doesn't work with Ubuntu or ask for it in another question.

Comment: OK. It's good to know  that is reproduced by other